# Wordpress - Migrate site with BackWPup to local environment. Url issue

Tags: wordpress, url, installation

I am using the plugin BackWPup to migrate my site, to a local environment for testing.

My problem is the url's. They point back to the site online and not my site locally.

I am using xampp and phpmyadmin.

This is my first migration. The database is connected and everything seems to work, except for the url's. Where can i change the url's? Do i need to change it in the database. If so which table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem.

I followed these tutorial.
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-a-wordpress-site-to-a-new-domain-and-hosting/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

After you done this, remember to go directly to.
www.yoursite.com/**wp-admin**

Check your permanent links

Hope this helps someone else.